# Execute commands on fish of WSL via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed WSL(Ubuntu) and now I'm wanting to access fish from WSL and execute a command like **date** from it. How can I do so?

Here's is my attempt!

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["wsl", "fish"], shell=True)
subprocess.run(["date"], shell=True)
```

The output shows the execution until the 2nd line of the code but not the execution of **date** command in the **fish** terminal. Any solution to do so?

Comment: Are you running that from Windows Python or WSL?

Comment: I am using Windows python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to capture the output, the most efficient invocation should be:

```
cp = subprocess.run(["wsl", "-e", "date"], capture_output=True)
date = cp.stdout
```

By specifying `-e`, you skip the shell entirely, which avoids the overhead of the shell starting up.

If you really do want to force it to run within `fish`:

```
cp = subprocess.run(["wsl", "-e", "fish", "-c", "date"], capture_output=True)
date = cp.stdout
```

---

*More detail:*

If `fish` is your default shell, then you really don't need to specify it as an argument to the `wsl` command.  You can see this by trying the following in PowerShell or CMD:

```
wsl ps -eH
```

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
   21 ?        00:00:00   init
   22 ?        00:00:00     init
   23 pts/0    00:00:00       fish
   30 pts/0    00:00:00         ps
```

Note that the `ps` command, although run without `fish` on the WSL command-line, still runs under the default shell.

However, you don't *have* to.  If a command doesn't *need* the shell, you can run it directly without going through a shell (avoids overhead) via:

```
wsl -e ps -ef
```

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
   11 ?        00:00:00   init
   12 ?        00:00:00     init
   13 pts/0    00:00:00       ps
```

You'll notice that no shell is running.  This is the variation I recommended above with the `["wsl","-e","date"]` in Python.

Let's say that `fish` isn't your default shell, and yet you do want it to run.

```
wsl -e fish -c "ps -eH"
```

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
   20 ?        00:00:00   init
   21 ?        00:00:00     init
   22 pts/0    00:00:00       fish
   29 pts/0    00:00:00         ps
```

But don't do `wsl fish "ps -eH"` (or `wsl fish -c date`).  That will run fish within fish, which is very wasteful:

```
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
   11 ?        00:00:00   init
   12 ?        00:00:00     init
   13 pts/0    00:00:00       fish
   20 pts/0    00:00:00         fish
   22 pts/0    00:00:00           ps
```

Answer (score 3):

With your command, the first `subprocess.run()` starts a process and then waits for it to finish. As you're aware, `wsl fish` doesn't actually finish by itself, meaning your python app will now block indefinitely.

What you actually want to do is start a process, send data to it through its STDIN, and read its STDOUT output.

You can't quite do it like this though- for 1, you don't want to block the interpreter!

```
proc = Popen(["wsl", "fish"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate(b"date")
print(output)
```

`communicate` also blocks. If you wanted to keep this running you'd do `proc.stdin.write()` followed by `proc.stdout.readline()`

Answer (score 0):

The first subprocess.run will start an interactive fish shell.

Only when you type exit, then `date` will run.