# Start WSL Script from WPF C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to run a bash script using WSL from a WPF application. I have been using the Process.Start() method to try and run this script, passing some arguments along with it. I thought I had this function running perfectly before, however I am struggling to get the script to run on WSL.

Here is the code I have below, I can include the WSL script if needed.
I need to run the WSL script and pass some arguments to the script from the command line.

```
string path = "\"" + store.LPFolderPath + "\"";
        Debug.WriteLine(path);
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();
        if(p.StandardInput.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"wsl");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd path/To/Script");
                                      //"./lpass == scriptFile "//
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"./lpass " + `ARG`);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            p.StandardInput.Close();
        };

        p.WaitForExit();
```

From what I know this script does not run at all. Is there a mistake I am making utilizing `Process` or how would I go about debugging this C# call in order to find out my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds me a bit of two questions I answered around using Python to launch WSL applications:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69586798/11810933) was using a subprocess.
- And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71239268/11810933) was using a SendKeys method.

In your case, you are attempting to use standard input, but I *think* the issue is similar.  The first `WriteLine` launches WSL, but I believe it's now a separate process with its own standard input.  The additional lines of standard input are probably going to the *original* process `p`, but are probably just waiting there until the WSL process terminates, which doesn't happen until your parent process terminates.  Disclaimer - I haven't tried this myself; I'm just basing it on past experience with other languages.

The solution should be the same as I mention in the other answers -- Use arguments to the `wsl` command itself to call your script.  E.g.:

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"wsl --cd path/To/Script -e bash -c lpass");
```

Or something similar.  Try it from the command-line first:

```
wsl --cd path/To/Script -e bash -c lpass
```

The `-e` tells it to run the Bash shell, with the `-c` passing the `./lpass` directly to Bash.  The `--cd` is also a WSL argument which will set the initial starting directory, although it should be possible to move it into the Bash command as well:

```
wsl -e bash -c "cd path/To/Script; ./lpass"
```

If the `lpass` script has a shebang line, you can even bypass calling Bash:

```
wsl --cd path/to/Script -e ./lpass
```