# How to launch from Windows a Linux program in Linux Subsystem?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to start (specifically from Windows Python3) a Linux program to be run in WSL?

If so, how?

Reason for this is I have a (complex) python script that, among other things, launches an external filter (written in C) to decode certain messages.

This works OK under Linux.

Now I have been asked to port it to Windows.

Problem is I have said filter in binary form only for Linux (actually I have sources for the most of it, as I wrote the filter, but it uses an external proprietary library I have only for Linux).

Is there some (easy??) way to launch a program under WSL?

The filter is currently started with:

```py
    def extract(fn):
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'filter'), fn], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
            lis = json.load(p.stderr)
            p.wait()
            if p.returncode != 0:
                raise ValueError()
        except (ValueError, json.JSONDecodeError):
            return None
        return lis
```

The filter opens a file and prints JSON-formatted output on `stderr`; I can change this behavior as required (e.g.: reading from one file and writing to another).

Problem is I should be able to start it not directly (under Windows), but under Linux Subsystem and be able to transport files across Win <-> WSL (I could make it a "real filter" reading from `stdin` and writing to `stdout`/`stderr`), but main problem remains:

How do I launch a program designed to run in WLS from "normal Windows" (and specifically from Python, but I can write another wrapper, if needed).

Comment: Take a look at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69586798/11810933) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71239268/11810933) and the answers there.  I think you'll find some ideas.  I'm a bit worried about the performance of running the filter through WSL from Windows Python, though, just because it seems the application will have to go back through the WSL init process for *each* input.